# When do I have to surround with try/catch?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have some piece of code:

```
public static void a() throws NumberFormatException {
        return;
    }

    public static void b() throws InterruptedException{
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        a();
        b();

    }
```

And Eclipse says that I have to surround try/catch to function call b(), but I do not have to do that with a() call. Why? How to make function make to surround with try and catch when is called?

Comment: Have a look at checked vs unchecked exceptions in Java - http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `InterruptedException` is a checked exception and `NumberFormatException` is an unchecked expcetion.

For checked exception, compiler forces you to either surround them with `try-catch` block or declare them with `throws`, while for unchecked exceptions `try-catch` block is not compulsory.

As function `a()` throws `NumberFormatException` (unchecked exception) compiler do not force you to surround the function call with `try-catch`.

As function `b()` throws `InterruptedException` (checked exception) compiler forces you to either surround the function call with `try-catch` or declare them with `throws`.

Comment: The compiler doesn't force you to surround the checked exception with a try-catch in this case. You could also rethrow it: `public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException`

Comment: You are correct, I will update my answer, it should be either `catch` or declare as `throws`

Answer (score 2):

`NumberFormatException` is not a checked Exception(i.e because it has java.lang.RuntimeException as its base class), which means that the developer is not forced to handle(its the developer's choice whether to handle it or not) when the developer chooses not to handle the exception and if the exception occurs, it will be handled by the JVM.

Where as `InterruptedException` (i.e because it has java.lang.Exception as its base class) is a checked exception which means that the developer has to handle it every time either by using a try-catch block or by declaring the exception in the Throws clause.

Take a look at this [example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/12/checked-vs-unchecked-exception-in-java.html).

Comment: and with "user" he means "developer", i guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `NumberFormatException` extends `RuntimeException` - i.e. it is `unchecked` exception. While `InterruptedException` is `checked` exception - it should be catched in `try...catch` block, or you should add `throws` to `main()` method.

Answer (score 1):

because NumberFormatException() is unchecked exception InterruptedException is checked, you have to surroud checked exceptions with try-catch, but you dont have to try-catch checked - every method would have try-catch then.

Answer (score 1):

NumberFormatException is a RuntimeException -> unchecked

InterruptedException is a checked Exception

I found the Java Tutorial quite useful to learn about Java and its APIs, and in fact, I still use it from time to time:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

public class InterruptedException
extends Exception
Thrown when a thread is waiting, sleeping, or otherwise occupied, and the thread is interrupted, either before or during the activity. Occasionally a method may wish to test whether the current thread has been interrupted, and if so, to immediately throw this exception.

but for the first case it will not ask NumberFormatException is an unchecked expcetion.

Answer (score 0):

All `Exception` that extends `RuntimeException` do not imply an explicit try-catch block. They are called `Unchecked`. Those exception were theoretically reserved to unrecoverable runtime errors thrown by VM. However they are now commonly used as lot's of people agree to say the `Checked` exceptions mechanism is a bad design concept.

You will commonly use `Unchecked` when your program cannot recover from the error and let them propagate to a transverse layer exception handling that will be in charge to properly log and / or display the error to user.

Checked exception are commonly used in cases where the caller will be expected to handle the error, because it is able to recover from it or will trigger specific behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The Keyword `throws` declares that a method may throw that exception. While checked exceptions have to be handled with unchecked exceptions this is optional. In your case a throws a [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) which is derived from RuntimeException which is according to the definition an unchecked exception, see [Section 11.2: Compile-Time Checking of Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#44121):

> The unchecked exceptions classes are the class RuntimeException and
>   its subclasses, and the class Error and its subclasses. All other
>   exception classes are checked exception classes.

And according to the definition the InterruptedException which class b throws is a checked exceptions (must be caught in a try-catch block).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in Java to handle exceptions -

```
1. surround try/catch
2. propagate exeption
```

you use try/catch block if you want to handle this exception locally. Basically, within the `try` block is a code that has a potential of throwing an exception.

but you use `throws SomeException` in the method signature if you want this possible `exception` to be handled by the `calling method`... this `calling method` can also propagate this `exception` further up... should all methods never `try/catch` this exception, it will be thrown by the `Java Virtual Machine` at `execution time`